# How to assign i unique ID or key to SwitchListTile and retrieve/get its value in onChanged in flutter mobile app

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, issue-tracking

I am building 9 SwitchListTile using for loop, as now the button contains same code so am having trouble
in its `onChanged` as my each button will have specific event to perform, how should i achieve it? Is it possible to send the button text/id or anything unique based on which i can perform the specific tasks?

Here `_onChanged(value, counter);` 'counter' is nothing but you can assume a variable in for loop assigning values 1-9 for each button. So Onchange i should know which button was pressed!.

I tried assigning `// key: ValueKey(counter),` to SwitchListTile constructor but was unable to retrieve that value in `onChanged`.

```
class MySwitchListTilesContainer extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[800],
      body: ListView(
        children: List.generate(20, (i)=>MySwitchListTile(

        )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
class MySwitchListTile extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _MySwitchListTileState createState() => new _MySwitchListTileState();
}

class _MySwitchListTileState extends State<MySwitchListTile> {
  bool _v = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  SwitchListTile(
      value:_v,
      onChanged: (value) {
          _onChanged(value, counter);
        },


    );
  }
}

void _onChanged(bool _v, int index) {
    setState(() {
      _v = _v;
      if (index == 1) {

        print(index);

      } else {
       print(index +1);
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can pass `callback` to use in `onChanged`

code snippet

```
ListView(
        children: List.generate(
            20,
            (i) => MySwitchListTile(
                  v: false,
                  callback: () {
                    print("index is $i");
                    setState(() {
                    });
                  },
                )),
      )
...   
class MySwitchListTile extends StatefulWidget {
  final bool v;
  final VoidCallback callback;

...  
return SwitchListTile(
      value: widget.v,
      onChanged: (value) {
        widget.callback();
      },
    );
```

working demo

[image]

output of working demo

```
I/flutter ( 6597): index is 0
I/flutter ( 6597): index is 2
I/flutter ( 6597): index is 6
```

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MySwitchListTilesContainer extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MySwitchListTilesContainerState createState() => _MySwitchListTilesContainerState();
}

class _MySwitchListTilesContainerState extends State<MySwitchListTilesContainer> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[800],
      body: ListView(
        children: List.generate(
            20,
            (i) => MySwitchListTile(
                  v: false,
                  callback: () {
                    print("index is $i");
                    setState(() {
                    });
                  },
                )),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MySwitchListTile extends StatefulWidget {
  final bool v;
  final VoidCallback callback;

  const MySwitchListTile({Key key, this.v, this.callback}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MySwitchListTileState createState() => new _MySwitchListTileState();
}

class _MySwitchListTileState extends State<MySwitchListTile> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SwitchListTile(
      value: widget.v,
      onChanged: (value) {
        widget.callback();
      },
    );
  }
}

/*void _onChanged(bool _v, int index) {
  setState(() {
    _v = _v;
    if (index == 1) {
      print(index);
    } else {
      print(index + 1);
    }
  });
}*/

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MySwitchListTilesContainer(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the update, isn't there any other simpler way! like we have in javascript where we can find the input using class name.